# gesture to handle attributed text from two different views

Tags: ios, swift, gesture

I am trying to develop an app in which two view controllers stay side by side with attributed text in both of them. I would like to add a gesture that spans between the two views to capture the attributed text (each paragraph has different attributes). Something like this:[image: two views and one gesture]

The gesture should encompass the beginning and the end of the text to be selected in both view, and then trigger an event to handle both attributed texts.

How would you design such a gesture? (the main problem for me is how to go from a view to the other one)

Thanks,
Silvo

Comment: Sorry, but I'm a little lost on what you want to do. Do you want to be able to click and drag attributed text from one VC to the other?

Comment: No, I just want to intercept a bunch of text (actually, only the attributes) from both views at the same time.

Comment: Ok, so selecting a block of text from one will automatically select a block from the other too?

Comment: I want to select the text in one view and then select other text (independently) in the other view. The final outcome should be that the two selected texts are linked (though an SQLite database). Of course it could also be possible to start from two different selections that are then processes to obtain this. But it would be less elegant.